# How to update property inside a object in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I update "UserPhoneNumber" property value in "Data" property alone from this object. I have done only to change value of property and not nested object.

```
var updateProfile = generalSettingResponse.Select(x => settingsList.ContainsKey(x.Key) ? settingsList.First(y => y.Key.ToLower() == x.Key) : x);
```

**sample json object:**
{
"Name": "John",
"SNo": "1234",
"Data": {
"UserPhoneNumber": "9102287287",
"UserProfileName": "John"
}
}

Comment: Convert the json into an instance of a c# object and then update the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change property of json object,here is a demo:

SampleJObject:

```
{ "Name": "John", "SNo": "1234", "Data": { "UserPhoneNumber": "9102287287", "UserProfileName": "John" } }
```

Use the following code,the property `UserPhoneNumber` will be changed:

```
SampleJObject["Data"]["UserPhoneNumber"] = "0123456789";
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use this:

```
updateProfile.Data.UserPhoneNumber = "+18888888888";
```

That will only work if the setters in the class are public.

Comment: I need it for dynamic

Comment: You are playing with fire when you use dynamics.  99.99% of the time you will never need to use them because there will be a better way.  If you do use them I recommend putting them inside a try catch.  Can you look in the Watch and look at the structure there?

Comment: @AshwinKumar I think you need to show where and how you are getting `dynamic` from/with the JSON.